# Include folder into grails app

Tags: grails

I have a folder with content that i need to access from an application in grails. I put it in the root directory of the application, and development works well, but if I create a .WAR, the folder is not included. I try this:

```
grails.war.resources = { stagingDir, args ->
    copy( todir: "${stagingDir}/folder" ){
        fileset(dir: "folder")
    }
}
```

That include the folder, but i can't access it in the same way that i do in development.

How I can do something like this?
What is the correct way?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put it in the assets folder. Or in the web-app folder if You are using an older version.

Comment: @MikelisBaltruks And how I access the folder later?

Comment: I think the web-app folder is the root in the production.

Comment: @MikelisBaltruks this work for me : grailsApplication.parentContext.getResource("/").file.toString(). Thanks for yor help !!

Comment: Sure. Then post that as an answer yourself. And accept it, do this thread would close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work for me:
Copy the folder for web-app and then accessed as follows:

```
grailsApplication.parentContext.getResource("/").file.toString()
```

So I access the web-app root in production and development